# How to shutdown CachedObservable

Tags: android, rx-java

I have endless stream (which is not called onComplete at all). And I cache last value in it:

```
Observable<T> endlessStream = createStream().cache();

Subscription s1 = endlessStream.subscribe(...)
Subscription s2 = endlessStream.subscribe(...)
```

By some condition `endlessStream` become not valid and I replace it (with switchMap, but it's not important).

```
s1.unsubscribe()
s2.unsubscribe()
```

But CachedObservable will always store connection to source stream (returned from `createStream()`). This leads to memory leak.
How to disconnect `CachedObservable` from source observable?

More information:

`CachedObservable` contains field `state`, which contain SerialSubscription to source observables (`connection`).
If I call next hack, everything becomes OK:

```
private void disconnectCachedObservable(CachedObservable<T> observable) {
    try {
        Field fieldState = CachedObservable.class.getDeclaredField("state");
        fieldState.setAccessible(true);
        Object state = fieldState.get(observable);
        Field fieldConnection = state.getClass().getDeclaredField("connection");
        fieldConnection.setAccessible(true);
        SerialSubscription subscription = (SerialSubscription) fieldConnection.get(state);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But reflection isn't good solution:(

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

Operator cache have similar behavior as operator replay + autoConnect(1).

```
replay().autoConnect(1, toStop -> { /* store Subscription to cancel later */ });
```

which let's you stop the upstream by giving you a Subscription.